# How to check each row/column/region in a Sudoku Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I continue my Sudoku but i need your help. I'm blocked here :

```
def grid_index(grid, value):
    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == value:
                return i, j
    return -1, -1


def can_fill_cell(sudoku, coords):
    row = sudoku[0]
    for cell in row:
        if cell == value_to_input:
            return False

    column = [row[0] for row in sudoku]
    for cell in column:
        if cell == value_to_input:
            return False

    square = [sudoku[x][y] for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]
    for cell in square:
        if cell == value_to_input:
            return False

    return True


def solve_next_unsolved(sudoku):
    """
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            coords = x,y
    """
    coords = (2,2)
    if can_fill_cell(sudoku, coords):
        sudoku[coords[0]][coords[1]] = value_to_input
        print(sudoku)
```

So, in grid_index, i get all cell coordinates.

In my can_fill_cell function i said : "If a value is equal to the value to input, break the for and get out the function to return False and not input the value"

The problem i have right now, it's i don't know how to verify all row, column and region...

Do you have any idea please ?

Thx,
Ravaniss

EDIT : Just for information, i get my sudoku like this :

```
value_to_input = "1"

def import_sudoku():
    with open("sudoku.txt") as f:
        lines = f.read()

    sudoku = [[character for character in line if not character == " "] for line in lines.split("\n")]

    return sudoku

sudoku = import_sudoku()
print(sudoku)
```

Si, right now i can verify :

```
.2.
.2.
...
```

that's not print the result, so it's false but i can do this :

```
...
1..
...

.2.
22.
...
```

for example. what i need to verify. How can i verify all of this and make my sudoku work ?

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like your sudoku is a list of lists, e.g.

```
[ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3],
  [7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   ... ]
```

You'll need to verify rows and columns separately, but those are the easy ones.

```
for row in sudoku:
    verify(row)
for col in zip(*sudoku):
    verify(col)
# zip(*iterable) is a very useful idiom for flipping rows to columns
```

The harder one is the 3x3s. Since this is a known quantity (9x9 sudoku), it's probably easier to just enumerate it rather than calculate it yourself.

```
grids = [ [s[0][0], s[0][1], s[0][2],
           s[1][0], s[1][1], s[1][2],
           s[2][0], s[2][1], s[2][2]],
          ... ]
```

Though this is certainly time consuming, it's also *straightforward* which counts for a lot. You could use `itertools.product` to simplify this instead:

```
grids = [ [s[y][x] for x, y in itertools.product(range(i, i+3), repeat=2)]
          for i in range(1, 8, 3) ]
```

Either way you have a new set of numbers to check.

```
for grid in grids:
    verify(grid)
```

`verify` in this case is probably easiest to implement just by checking for duplicates

```
def verify(group):
    return len(group) == len(set(group))
```

Though you could verify it against the literal if you like

```
def verify(group):
    return sorted(group) == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: for col in zip(*sudoku):
    verify(col)

How can i change that for something more understandable ?

I am looking for itertools.product for know what is this. I don't want to copy paste without knowing and understanding what it does.

Comment: @Ravaniss that's very idiomatic Python. Not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: I want to change the function zip() for something more understandable. zip(), map() and one other function (don't have the name) are not really cool to use. For understanding

Comment: You're thinking of map, filter, and reduce. Zip is very idiomatic